# What is a safe clearance for ground planes?

Tags: pcb-design, ground-plane

I am designing a board and the ground plane default clearance was set to 22 thou. I have been told in the past that a rule to thumb, with signal lines, is to work to "8 thou track and gap"

So is it safe to drop the ground plane clearance to 8 thou?

This means that the ground plane flows between all my signal lines, which I assume is good for reducing cross talk?

The highest voltage on the board is +12V with +/-5 and +3.3V supplies.

There are 6MHz and 20MHz clock signal but these don't run very far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the right answer can only truly be given by you and the person or people finally making the PCB. When I design with 5/5 track/clearance my pours often also become 5 or 8 clearance, because I know the fabs I use can do it at a price I am willing to pay and I know I will have taken care of larger gaps only where they are needed.

((I changed my wording to reflect what I think you mean. More usually planes are used to refer to the dedicated copper planes inside a multilayer PCB where no tracks run through them, where a pour is the copper areas you have on the signal layers of a given potential, such as a ground pour or VCC pour))

If you have no signals or pads that need to be further away from a ground pour for signal or thermal reasons or you know you have defined special rules for just those occasions, you can just set the general rule to 8 thou/mil as well. If you may have those signals and can't be sure everything takes that into account and on the other hand don't need to isolate your tracks from each other, you can keep it at 12, 15 or whatever.

Generally having ground between tracks can do little harm (unless the tracks it creeps between are characteristically coupled, like wired network, USB, RS485, etc) and often even improves things, especially if you do not have an actual ground plane on an internal layer.

Comment: Ace, thanks, that all I needed, just some confirmation that I wasn't breaking any important rules, also, the difference between copper pours and ground planes is nice to know :)

Comment: @TimMottram no worries. It's what the system is there for. It's not definitely wrong to call them planes, but knowing the difference between the words can help you with some confusion between you and a fab.

Answer (score 3):

Clearances required on inner planes of multilayer boards are necessitated by multiple factors... not just the electrical spacing criteria.

First, think about the end use of your product and what environment it will be subjected to. Then, before evaluating the nominal relationship think about the materials the board is made of and the flow characteristics of that material when laminated under heat and pressure.(not all boards are made from fiberglass epoxy laminate) The copper thickness, Also take into account the overall size of the panel that the manufacturer will be using to make the boards from... (standard size FR4 panels are typically 18x24 inches but large boards will need more spacing the farther you are drilling away from the center of the panel. Tolerances are cumulative and spread out from the center 0,0 of the x/y table that locates the material under the drill spindle.)

1. The desired finished hole diameter at LMC (least material
   condition or largest hole diameter tolerance limit)
2. The number of layers and stack-up structure of your board design. b)
   The hole locational tolerance with respect to the copper image on
   the layer.  (this is established by the manufacturer's machine
   tolerances and can be affected by potential movement of the inner
   layers when laminating the board materials)
3. The voltage potential between the circuits that are connected to the
   pad and plane on the inner or outer layer. (you can find guidelines
   for electrical spacing and creepage in IPC 2221B Table 6.)

Why? Because the manufacturer laminates the materials with printed and etched copper layers before drilling and plating thru the holes. The pressure and heat applied to the fiberglass epoxy makes it squish out the edges of the 'layer-cake' structure like a squished peanut butter and jelly sandwich pressed between two books. The edges the furthest from the center of the sandwich 'oozing out' with flowing epoxy resin **and the copper patterns** that are printed on the b-stage epoxy stretch out towards the edges of the board misaligning the pad patterns printed on them from the theoretical true position that they were designed to.

When the drilling happens there is about a +/- 2 mil 'runout' tolerance on the drill that can get worse with age of the drilling machine due to wearing of the bearings and also with stack drilling of boards for production caused by wandering of the drill as it goes through the multiple layers of the stacked boards causing the farthest layer from the point of entry into the board surface to not be perfectly aligned with the exit point of the drilled hole. (the drill can bend while drilling)

The pad size around this hole must take into account these limitations in the manufacturing process or you will have breakout of the hole from the pad pattern in your holes.

The voltage spacing must take this positional tolerance issue with misaligned holes and pads into account when calculation the min spacing between copper features... not just the nominal location or true position as designed in the cad model. creepage of a plated pad in the cleared ring area in a plane must account for the hole to be misaligned with the copper place clearance area... not perfectly centered.

Often, drill machines can be programmed to compensate for misaligned pads from layer to layer by splitting the difference between the converging areas of the pads to place the hole offset in the largest area of overlapping coverage keeping the hole inside all of the pad lands and consequently reducing the annual ring of certain misaligned pads in the stack-up... but making electrical connections thru the misaligned pads with the plating in the holes.

An x-ray machine can be used to align the patterns and the drill program to see the internal layers of the board copper patterns and see how much they have deviated from nominal to make the compensation drill program work.

Bottom-line check with your board manufacturer to see what the minimum gap between the pad and hole is needed to clear the copper planes, then add up your tolerances and give yourself some margin when choosing a clearance rule for your plane clearances. Try to give your manufacturer a fighting chance to build your board successfully. :)
Never design a board to the minimums if you don't actually need to. It makes the job harder to build, more failures, more scrap and rejected materials, more cost, reduced reliability, etc.